# Bad behavior when merging into an empty Git repository

Tags: git, git-subtree

I'm following Github doc's subtree merges, and I noticed an odd and bad behavior. This is the code (numbered for reference):

```
#1: git remote add -f <some_dir> <clone_url>
#2: git merge -s ours --no-commit --allow-unrelated-histories <remote_branch>
#3: git read-tree --prefix=<some_dir> -u <remote_branch>
```

So if you perform this on an existing repository (at least 1 commit), then no problem. Everything is fine, and you can add as many subtrees as you want.

BUT if you made a fresh `git init` directory and *have not committed anything yet*, this causes two issues:

- The remote repository content is copied **once into your base** and again into your new `<some_dir>` (where it should be ONLY), creating a duplication issue.
- When you try to add future subtrees, you may run into a complication wherein `#2` fails with a "merge strategy ours" failure message. Removing the `-s ours` option, it'll tell you a bunch of things (basically your previous subtree and current repo)  **will be overwritten**.

I'm working around this by checking for the existence of any commit in my sh script (`test -z "$(git rev-list -n1 --all)"`), but out of curiosity, can someone enlighten me as to what's going on?

Comment: The `git merge` command operates on commits. If you have no commits, there is nothing to operate on. The `git merge` command *should* refuse to run here, but perhaps the ours strategy code fails to notice this fundamental issue.

Comment: BTW if you just want to repeatedly read other trees into your (currently empty) index after steps 0 (git init) and 1 and the missing 1.5 (`git fetch`), just skip straight to step 3 at that point.

Comment: Oh, I see thanks. Would that still be valid if the index isn't empty and there are conflicting files?

Comment: The `--prefix=<prefix>` documentation for `git read-tree` says, in part: "The command will refuse to overwrite entries that already existed in the original index file." You'll have to experiment to see what that means: does the entire `read-tree` get aborted, or do the non-conflicting entries get written?